# Remove Nougat 7.1 launcher icon backaround completely

Tags: android, icons, launcher

I am tired to searching this problem . for 2 days i tested different modes to fix problem , But i failed  .

I create icon in `photoshop` with `512 * 512` size and adding on `minmap` from `image asset` option on `Android Studio 3.0.1` . i put `none` for all shaps on `legancy`. On all android versions my icon is ok but in android 7.1 and higher android adding circlier backaround for icon . how can i fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: can you show the project folder structure?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0):

You should select icon type : **Launcher Icon (Legacy only)**

[image]

Comment: I do this . but in android 7.1 and higher my icon is small and have backaround too

Comment: just put ic_launcher in mip folder and remove all extra files

Comment: Yeah . `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`

Comment: then Remove this.

Comment: I remove all files and again set icon with `launcher icons(Legancy only)` . but i have backaround yet

Comment: Did you remove `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166799/discussion-between-vishal-g-gohel-and-b4hr4m).